# pymssql bulk insert error (python)

Tags: python

Trying to bulk insert a CSV file using pymssql here's the code:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host='server', user='user', password='secret', database='My_Dev')
cur = conn.cursor()
load = 'BULK INSERT TempStaging FROM \'/home/dross/python/scripts/var/csv/' + f + '.csv\' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = \'\\n\') GO")'
cur.execute(load)
```

When executing get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./uploadResults.py", line 46, in <module>
    cur.execute(sweepload)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 447, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:7092)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1009, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:11585)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1040, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:11459)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1160, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query (_mssql.c:12652)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 203, in _mssql.ensure_bytes (_mssql.c:2733)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Line 46 is cur.execute line

Comment: Use triple quotes with SQL. `',',ROWTERMINATOR` isn't escaped

Comment: @Wayne Werner:Using the following:
**load = 'BULK INSERT TempStaging FROM \'/home/dross/python/scripts/var/csv/' + filename + '.csv\' WITH (FIRSTROW = 1,FIELDTERMINATOR = \',\',ROWTERMINATOR = \'\\n\')'**
Is this equivalent to what you meant ?(I'm python beginner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `.format()` could allow [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), but if you control the filename then it's not that bad (not sure if a parameter would work here).

Also, you should use triple-quoted strings when dealing with SQL, your life will be so much better. Like this:

```
load = '''BULK INSERT TempStaging FROM /home/dross/python/scripts/var/csv/{}.csv WITH (FIRSTROW=1, FIELDTERMINATOR=',', ROWTERMINATOR='\n')'''.format(filename)
```

Being triple quoted, you can also break it up to make it easier to read:

```
load = '''
    BULK INSERT TempStaging
    FROM /home/dross/python/scripts/var/csv/{}.csv
    WITH (
        FIRSTROW=1
      , FIELDTERMINATOR=','
      , ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
    )
'''.format(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should defined the string as below:

```
load = "BULK INSERT TempStaging FROM /home/dross/python/scripts/var/csv/" + f + ".csv  WITH ( FIRSTROW=1 , FIELDTERMINATOR=',' , ROWTERMINATOR='\\n')"
```